# My output is always "1"

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a miles per gallon calculator with C#, but my output is always "1" no matter the input. 
Is my equation not created correctly? I am supposed to base my code off of a previous assignment which looks very similar, so (if possible) try to help me find a way to keep the same relative structure to the code.

Thank you so much for any help!

Here is my code:

```
namespace Miles_Per_Gallon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            float Miles, Gallons, MPG;
            string textline;

            Console.Write("Miles Traveled :");
            textline = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Gallons of Gas Used :");
            textline = Console.ReadLine();

            Miles = float.Parse(textline);
            Gallons = float.Parse(textline);
            MPG = Miles / Gallons;

            Console.Write("Miles Per Gallon :  ");
            Console.WriteLine(MPG.ToString());


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Also, in programming always name your variables so that you cant make this mistake.. it should read like english not  like a cryptic writing.

Comment: Sorry for asking a bad question..? Why all the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix one, try this and compare with your old code, you should figure out the problem.

```
float Miles, Gallons, MPG;
string textline;

Console.Write("Miles Traveled :");
textline = Console.ReadLine();
Miles = float.Parse(textline); //Store to variable

Console.Write("Gallons of Gas Used :");
textline = Console.ReadLine();        
Gallons = float.Parse(textline); //Store to variable


MPG = Miles / Gallons;

Console.Write("Miles Per Gallon :  ");
Console.WriteLine(MPG.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Okay, that makes total sense now. Thank you for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it!

Comment: "Try this and figure out problem" is very bad form of answer. @ColeUdall if you ever decide to answer questions on SO take note of this one as bad (almost deserving downvote) example of an answer.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: Sorry but I think there is no common formula for all thing, good or bad is just the matter of opinion, someone learn this way, other learn other way, you can't force everyone follow your way. It depends on the situation. The situation here is for newbie, not for familiar one.

Comment: Jesus christ you guys here are not friendly at all. I am asking a question, and i got an answer. I am pleased as punch, so I suggest you stop getting so upset someone helped me how they could. I don't understand why this forum is so hostile. Not coming back here again.

Comment: Thanks @123iamking, exactly. I'm obviously a newbie and have no idea what I'm doing and your answer helped me learn.

Comment: @ColeUdall - don't worry friend, people here aren't un-friendly, they are just trying to keep this website great :) check this: How do I ask a good question? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable `textline` to store both miles and gallons input. And when you divide them together you'll get 1. 
Use different variables  to get input of both miles and gallons

Comment: How do I use a different textline for the variables?

I'm sorry, I'm very new at this. And my professor isn't the greatest teacher...

Comment: I see you got the answer now. You were not saving the data to a variable before inputting a new one.